# How do they know the Jackal's name even though "Victor Wolenski" never reveals any information?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-day-of-the-jackal

In *The Day of the Jackal (1973)*, French officials abducted *Victor Wolenski* and torture him about who is behind the assassination mission of the French President.

He never reveals it clearly. But somehow they guess it that he is saying *Jackie* or *Jackal*.

There is no way to guess the name because he always shouts **AAAAAAAAAA**.. that's it. There is no word sounding near to **J** while investigating him.

So how did they get his name?

Comment: In the book at least, Wolenski does not say "jackal".  He says "_chacal_" -- French for jackal.  In the movie version, he might be saying the same, or _szakal_, in the Legionnaire's native Polish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you listen closely to the tape of the 'interrogation', just after his last, loudest agonized scream, Wolenksi *whispers* the word 'jackal' [it is quite hard to hear, especially coming from a TV broadcast].  They tentatively conclude that this is in fact the code-name of the assassin, rather than Wolenski *calling the interrogator* a jackal.